# Data table is not showing in proper format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

In my code data table is not showing in proper format. data is showing in the data table but table is missing borders. I am attaching code and screen shot. please find the attachment.Please help.

### Code:-

```
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
<table id="ex">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Number of accounts</th>
        <th>Number of BUs</th>
        <th>Total salesop</th>
        <th>Number of dormant accounts</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>    
</table>
    </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
     <link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/jquery.multiselect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/assets/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/assets/prettify.css" />    
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/StyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/assets/prettify.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fourth_page.js"></script>
```

### Jquery:-

```
$('#ex').dataTable({

                    "aaData": data,
                    "aoColumns": [{ "mData": "FirstNamecount" },
                        { "mData": "LastNamecount" },
                        { "mData": "Salary" },
                        { "mData": "Gendercount" }],
                    retrieve: true,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    paging: false,

                }).fnDestroy();
```

[image: Data table is not showing properly,please see this image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/5hj276ej/2/

Html

```
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
<table id="example"  class="cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
             </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

JS Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#example').DataTable({

     "paging": false,
     // "retrieve": true
     "bDestroy": true,
    });
} );
```